# Windows 8 VPN PPTP Settings

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn, pptp

I am having a problem getting my computer to connect to my companies VPN, the thing is it connects just fine from my Android phone with the default settings so I know it is a problem with the settings in Windows. I have tried just about every setting to no avail.
Here is what our IT said:
Encryption Level – should just be “auto”
Proxy – can also be “auto”

Which didn't help much, my settings are currently:
Type: PPTP
Encryption: Require
Authentication has nothing selected.

If the default android settings work why won't the default windows settings work? any help would be greatly appreciated.